# cyclic dependency detected in mongoose + nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean

I'm getting error like below.

> Error: cyclic dependency detected
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:331:34)

The code is as below..

In db.connection.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mean");
require("./hotel.model");
```

In hotel.schema.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const HotelSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : [true, "Hotel name is required"]
    },
    stars : {
        type : Number,
        min : 0,
        max : 5,
        default : 0
    },
    description : String,
    services : [String]
});

mongoose.model("Hotel",HotelSchema);
```

In server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");

const mongoose = require(path.join(__dirname,"server","db","db.connection"));

const routes = require("./server/routes")
const app = express();
port = 3000;
app.set("port",port);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"dist")));

app.use("/api",routes);

app.use('*',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname,"dist","index.html");
});

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port,()=>console.log("listening to port : "+port));
```

so when I'm running the "node server.js", I'm getting the error as mentioned at the beginning.

Full stack trace:

> F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:440
>           throw err;
>           ^
>
> Error: cyclic dependency detected
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:331:34)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)
>       at serializeObject (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:345:18)
>       at serializeInto (F:\Full Stack course\code_base\meanhotel\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\parser\serializer.js:934:17)

Can someone please help me in solving this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error is not coming from anything in this code. Look at the full stack trace as it will indicate which part of your code it actually comes from. If you still cannot work that out, then actually include the full stack tract within your question.

Comment: I don't think it is because of 
const mongoose = require(path.join(__dirname,"server","db","db.connection"));

because if I remove the HotelSchema related code and put some logger on db connect, everything is working good.

I guess something is wrong with Schema

Comment: i tried creating same directory structure alongwith your code and everything worked fine. May be you can delete and install node module again and try, not sure but just a thought

Comment: My mongo db version is v3.6.3 and mongoose version is 5.1.3.

By googling I found it is a version specific issue, ref: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6109

but couldn't find a solution. Please refer to the comment made by "gustvao". But I'm not using any parameter like index.

Answer (score 4):

Update your mongoose, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Please consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After you have gained enough reputation points you shall be able to post comments in other questions/answers.

Comment: Yes, I was going to post a comment only but as i'm new they did not let me do it so I just post the solution this way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in the end of your hotel.schema.js file can help

```
HotelSchema.set('autoIndex', false);
```