# Hi! I'm getting a cyclic dependency error

Tags: mongodb, apollo, express-graphql

I'm trying to use graphql + apollo + mongodb. But I keep getting this cyclic dependency error.
I'm trying to make a react app a recipe app.

Here's the error [cyclic dependecy detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTIX5.jpg)

Here's [my schema.js, resolvers.js and server.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpfvL.jpg)

Here'
s [my mongo models.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TK54.jpg)

Comment: Might be a duplicate, check this link out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54991599/6325212

Comment: Oh!!! ive added it to both of my models it seems to be working now however I dont understand why it worked though.

Comment: Yes!! would like an explanation though